# localStorage.length does not work in my code or?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have a basic input text and appended area.I am adding texts dynamically and wanted to count how many dynamic element i added.

So used localStorage.length  and it gives me always 1.

Do i have to add a specific key to count it?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sr4w18hf/4/)

```
$("#len").click(function() {
 alert(localStorage.length);
});
```

What is solution ?

Comment: You have only one item in your localStorage, and it is `box`.

Comment: How can i count how many element i have ?@callback

Comment: @MBurakErman you're already doing it

Comment: @MBurakErman, give items different names

Comment: So how ? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: How... what? Your code is already counting the number of elements you have stored in localStorage. With the logic you have, that number is always 1. Store more items and you'll see the count increase.

Comment: for example: localStorage.setItem(box, box);

Comment: If you want to count the elements you have added do `var box = $("#box br").length;`. Then if you want to read that back from local storage do `alert(localStorage.getItem('box')`

Comment: Its not working man , try it.  @PaulFrench

Comment: Here is a demo of what I think you are after?: https://jsfiddle.net/9j3zsLvt/

Comment: God! That is the easiest solution tho. Thank you! @PaulFrench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the count of your variable after each click. you also need to initialize the `box` variable in the beginning.

```
 localStorage.setItem('box', 0);
   $("#button").click(function() {
       var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('box'),10);
       var var1=$("#text").val();
       $("#text").val("");
       $("#box").append(var1+"<br>");
       localStorage.setItem('box', (count+1).toString());
    });
```

and in the alert you get the value like:

```
$("#len").click(function() {
 alert(localStorage.getItem('box'));
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sr4w18hf/18

Comment: Thanks! By the way your fiddle link is wrong, edit it